# Android webview display mobile page differently compared to a standard browser

Tags: android, webview

I have written a simple Android app to display wikipedia mobile page in a WebView:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
       // @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }
    });

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://en.m.wikipedia.org/");
}
```

[image: In my app]
[image: Same page in Chrome mobile]

As you can see in my app the side menu from Wikipedia's mobile page takes up the whole screen width. In Chrome, it displays correctly so it can tap to put the menu away.

How to I fix this? Thank you.

The above screenshots were done with this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

I subsequently tried linear layout, same result:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the layout.xml of your webview. Most probably the problem should be in that. I believe Wikipedia mobile page should handle a javascript disabled browser properly.

Comment: Thanks Sundeep. Added xml as above.

Comment: Is there a reason you chose RelativeLayout? Did you try if this works with a LinearLayout?

Comment: Thank you Sundeep. Tried just now but menu still taking the full screen width, no difference.

Comment: I just disabled Javascript in my browser and saw that `http://en.m.wikipedia.org/` redirects to `http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`. If I click on the stack icon, the url `http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MobileMenu` loads and I see what you see on screen shot. Try explicitly loading `http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`. If it doesn't work, try enabling Javascript in the embedded browser

Comment: Enable JavaScript did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Cool. Posting as answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enable Javascript for the embedded browser.`

I just disabled Javascript in my browser and saw that 
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/ redirects to http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page.

If I click on the stack icon, the url http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MobileMenu loads and I see what you see on screen shot.

Try explicitly loading http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page. I'd expect wikipedia mobile page to handle a javascript less browser and it seems to handle it fine on my PC.

Comment: Just to add, the explicit URL wasn't required. It was the Javascript enabling fixed it.